# Get list of redirect urls

Tags: python

I have a list of urls that all redirect to other urls . I would like to using python get a list of the redirected urls instead, wondering best way to go about doing this?

an example might be this: http://apple.co/1ka9kIX yielding apple.com

Comment: Please give example, you hope your inputs and outputs.

Comment: sure an example might be this: http://apple.co/1ka9kIX , yielding apple.com

Comment: It looks like this resource will be helpful: http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me, based on [a diveintopython tutorial](http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html).

```
import urllib2
import httplib

class SmartRedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
    """
    Stolen from http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html
    Originally defined in openanything.py

    """
    def http_error_301(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):  
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_301(
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)              
        result.status = code
        return result                                       

    def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
        result = urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler.http_error_302(
            self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)              
        result.status = code                                
        return result

inputURLs = ['http://apple.co/1ka9kIX', 'http://fb.com']
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
opener = urllib2.build_opener(SmartRedirectHandler())

getRedirect = lambda url: opener.open(urllib2.Request(url)).url

print map(getRedirect, inputURLs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `urllib2` and `httplib`, the below code:

```
import httplib
import urllib2

def get_request_direct(url):  
    httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1  
    req = urllib2.Request(url)  
    req.add_header("Accept", "text/html,*/*")  
    req.add_header("Connection", "Keep-Alive")  
    op = urllib2.build_opener()  
    f = op.open(req)  
    return f.url  

# if your url not start `http` or `https`, please add it.
>>> print get_request_direct('http://apple.co/1ka9kIX')
http://www.apple.com/
```